# Error when pressing an item in a listview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-database

I am developing a listview complete with a database.
When tapping an item of listview, the application closes and displays this error:

```
05-25 18:47:59.506  13297-13297/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-25 18:47:59.664  13297-13297/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
05-25 18:47:59.737  13297-13313/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
05-25 18:47:59.739  13297-13297/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6caeab0, tid 13297
05-25 18:47:59.773  13297-13297/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
05-25 18:47:59.798  13297-13297/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
05-25 18:47:59.833  13297-13313/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6cca100, tid 13313
05-25 18:47:59.876  13297-13313/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-25 18:47:59.892  13297-13313/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-25 18:47:59.903  13297-13313/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:47:59.903  13297-13313/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6ce2080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-25 18:48:00.192  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:48:00.193  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6ce20a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-25 18:48:00.956  13297-13297/com.example.mislugares I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-25 18:48:01.706  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:48:01.706  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6ce20a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-25 18:48:03.715  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:48:03.715  13297-13313/com.example.mislugares W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6ce20a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-25 18:48:14.024  13297-13297/com.example.mislugares D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-25 18:48:14.025  13297-13297/com.example.mislugares E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mislugares, PID: 13297
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mislugares/com.example.mislugares.VistaLugar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mislugares.GeoPunto cannot be cast to com.example.mislugares.GeoPuntoAlt
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mislugares.GeoPunto cannot be cast to com.example.mislugares.GeoPuntoAlt
            at com.example.mislugares.Lugares.elemento(Lugares.java:32)
            at com.example.mislugares.VistaLugar.actualizarVistas(VistaLugar.java:98)
            at com.example.mislugares.VistaLugar.onCreate(VistaLugar.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-25 18:48:14.048  13297-13309/com.example.mislugares W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.680ms
05-25 18:48:14.068  13297-13309/com.example.mislugares I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 597(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 14MB/18MB, paused 7.947ms total 12.964ms
```

The error refers to the line:

```
lugar.setPosicion((GeoPuntoAlt) new GeoPunto(cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4)));
```

This line is within the class Lugares.class

```
public class Lugares {

    private static LugaresBD lugaresBD;


    protected static List<Lugar> vectorLugares = ejemploLugares();

    public Lugares() {
        vectorLugares = ejemploLugares();
    }

    public static Lugar elemento(int id) {
        Lugar lugar = null;
        SQLiteDatabase bd = lugaresBD.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugares WHERE _id = " + id, null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            lugar = new Lugar();
            lugar.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            lugar.setDireccion(cursor.getString(2));
            lugar.setPosicion((GeoPuntoAlt) new GeoPunto(cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4)));
            lugar.setTipo(TipoLugar.values()[cursor.getInt(5)]);
            lugar.setFoto(cursor.getString(6));
            lugar.setTelefono(cursor.getInt(7));
            lugar.setUrl(cursor.getString(8));
            lugar.setComentario(cursor.getString(9));
            lugar.setFecha(cursor.getLong(10));
            lugar.setValoracion(cursor.getFloat(11));
        }
        cursor.close();
        bd.close();
        return lugar;
    }

    static void anyade(Lugar lugar){
        vectorLugares.add(lugar);
    }

    final static String TAG = "MisLugares";
    protected static GeoPunto posicionActual = new GeoPunto(0,0);

    static int nuevo(){
        Lugar lugar = new Lugar("1Escuela Politécnica Superior de Gandía",
                "C/ Paranimf, 1 46730 Gandia (SPAIN)", -0.166093, 38.995656, 1500,
                TipoLugar.EDUCACION,962849300, "http://www.epsg.upv.es",
                "Uno de los mejores lugares para formarse.", 3);
        vectorLugares.add(lugar);
        return vectorLugares.size()-1;
    }

    static void borrar(int id){
        vectorLugares.remove(id);
    }

    public static int size() {
        return vectorLugares.size();
    }

    public static ArrayList<Lugar> ejemploLugares() {
        ArrayList<Lugar> lugares = new ArrayList<Lugar>();
        lugares.add(new Lugar("Escuela Politécnica Superior de Gandía",
                "C/ Paranimf, 1 46730 Gandia (SPAIN)", -0.166093, 38.995656, 800,
                TipoLugar.EDUCACION,962849300, "http://www.epsg.upv.es",
                "Uno de los mejores lugares para formarse.", 3));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("Al de siempre",
                "P.Industrial Junto Molí Nou - 46722, Benifla (Valencia)",
                -0.190642, 38.925857, 150, TipoLugar.BAR, 636472405, "",
                "No te pierdas el arroz en calabaza.", 3));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("androidcurso.com",
                "ciberespacio", 0.0, 0.0, 2000, TipoLugar.EDUCACION,
                962849300, "http://androidcurso.com",
                "Amplia tus conocimientos sobre Android.", 5));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("Barranco del Infierno",
                "Vía Verde del río Serpis. Villalonga (Valencia)",
                -0.295058, 38.867180, 000, TipoLugar.NATURALEZA,

                0, "http://sosegaos.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/lorcha-villalonga-via-verde-del-rio.html",
                "Espectacular ruta para bici o andar", 4));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("La Vital",
                "Avda. de La Vital, 0 46701 Gandía (Valencia)",
                -0.1720092, 38.9705949, 400, TipoLugar.COMPRAS,
                962881070, "http://www.lavital.es/",
                "El típico centro comercial", 2));

        return lugares;

    }

    static List listaNombres(){
        ArrayList resultado = new ArrayList();
        for (Lugar lugar:vectorLugares){
            resultado.add(lugar.getNombre());
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    public static void indicializaBD(Context contexto){
        lugaresBD = new LugaresBD(contexto);
    }

    public static Cursor listado() {
        SQLiteDatabase bd = lugaresBD.getReadableDatabase();
        return bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugares", null);
    }

}
```

There is also another error on line:

```
    lugar = Lugares.elemento((int) id);
```

This line is within the class VistaLugar.class

```
public class VistaLugar extends ActionBarActivity {
    private long id;
    private Lugar lugar;

    private ImageView imageView;
    final static int RESULTADO_EDITAR= 1;
    final static int RESULTADO_GALERIA= 2;
    final static int RESULTADO_FOTO= 3;
    private Uri uriFoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vista_lugar);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = extras.getLong("id", -1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
        actualizarVistas();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vista_lugar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.accion_compartir:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        lugar.getNombre() + " - "+ lugar.getUrl());
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.accion_llegar:
                verMapa(null);
                return true;
            case R.id.accion_editar:
                Intent i = new Intent(VistaLugar.this, EdicionLugar.class);
                i.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULTADO_EDITAR);
                return true;
            case R.id.accion_borrar:
                //Lugares.borrar((int) id);
                //finish();
                seVaaBorrar(null);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void seVaaBorrar(View view){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Confirmación de borrado")
                .setMessage("¿Seguro que desea borrar el lugar?")
                .setPositiveButton("Borrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Lugares.borrar((int) id);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null)
                .show();
    }

    public void actualizarVistas(){
        lugar = Lugares.elemento((int) id);
        TextView nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        nombre.setText(lugar.getNombre());
        ImageView logo_tipo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_tipo);
        logo_tipo.setImageResource(lugar.getTipo().getRecurso());
        TextView tipo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipo);
        tipo.setText(lugar.getTipo().getTexto());
        TextView direccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccion);
        if (lugar.getDireccion() == ""){
            findViewById(R.id.direccion).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.logo_myplaces).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            direccion.setText(lugar.getDireccion());
        }
        //direccion.setText(lugar.getDireccion());
        TextView telefono = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefono);
        if (lugar.getTelefono() == 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.telefono).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.logo_menucall).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            telefono.setText(Integer.toString(lugar.getTelefono()));
        }
        //telefono.setText(Integer.toString(lugar.getTelefono()));
        TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
        if (lugar.getUrl() == "") {
            findViewById(R.id.url).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.logo_mapmode).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            url.setText(lugar.getUrl());
        }
        //url.setText(lugar.getUrl());
        TextView comentario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comentario);
        if (lugar.getComentario() == "") {
            findViewById(R.id.comentario).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.logo_infodetails).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            comentario.setText(lugar.getComentario());
        }
        //comentario.setText(lugar.getComentario());
        TextView fecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        fecha.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(
                new Date(lugar.getFecha())));
        TextView hora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hora);
        hora.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(
                new Date(lugar.getFecha())));
        RatingBar valoracion = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.valoracion);
        valoracion.setRating(lugar.getValoracion());
        valoracion.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(
                new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                                          float valor, boolean fromUser) {
                        lugar.setValoracion(valor);
                    }
                });

        ponerFoto(imageView, lugar.getFoto());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULTADO_EDITAR) {
            actualizarVistas();
            findViewById(R.id.scrollView1).invalidate();
        }else if (requestCode == RESULTADO_GALERIA
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            lugar.setFoto(data.getDataString());
            ponerFoto(imageView, lugar.getFoto());
        }else if(requestCode == RESULTADO_FOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
                && lugar!=null && uriFoto!=null) {
            lugar.setFoto(uriFoto.toString());
            ponerFoto(imageView, lugar.getFoto());
        }
    }

    protected void ponerFoto(ImageView imageView, String uri) {
        /*if (uri != null) {
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        } else{
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }*/
        if (uri != null) {
            // imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
            Bitmap d = null;
            try {
                d = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(uri));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int nh = (int) (d.getHeight() * (254.0 / d.getWidth()));

            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 254, nh, true);
            //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else{
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    public void verMapa(View view) {
        Uri uri;
        double lat = lugar.getPosicion().getLatitud();
        double lon = lugar.getPosicion().getLongitud();
        if (lat != 0 || lon != 0) {
            uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + lat + "," + lon);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + lugar.getDireccion());
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void llamadaTelefono(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                Uri.parse("tel:" + lugar.getTelefono())));
    }


    public void pgWeb(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(lugar.getUrl())));
    }

    public void galeria(View view) {
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULTADO_GALERIA);*/
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent, RESULTADO_GALERIA);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULTADO_GALERIA);
        }
    }

    public void tomarFoto(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        uriFoto = Uri.fromFile(
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                        + "img_" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) + ".jpg"));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFoto);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULTADO_FOTO);
    }

    public void eliminarFoto(View view) {
        lugar.setFoto(null);
        ponerFoto(imageView, null);
    }

}
```

And in the same class line:

```
actualizarVistas();
```

Comment: Could you specify line 32 of `Lugares.java`?

Comment: lugar.setPosicion((GeoPuntoAlt) new GeoPunto(cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4)));

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Ups, Sorry for my manners. Sometimes I forget to be a person.
Thank you for correcting me, makes me better

Comment: is GeoPuntoAlt derived from GeoPunto, if so can you just change it to  new GeoPuntoAlt(......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception, `ClassCastException`, says that you have done an invalid class casting.

```
lugar.setPosicion((GeoPuntoAlt) new GeoPunto(cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4)));
```

In this line, you have casted output of `new GeoPunto(...)` to `GeoPuntoAlt`. Make sure this casting is valid.

Comment: I removed the cast and problem solved.

Thank you very much to all.